# Number Sequence starting in Cell <> A1

Tags: excel, vba

Want sequence to start on Cell A4.  so that A4 is 1, A5 is 2 et al to A1004 = 1004

Tried changing [Range("A" & I)..] to [Range("A4" & I)..]
Tried changing I=4

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim I As Integer
    I = 1
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For I = 1 To 1000
        Range("A" & I).Value = I
    Next
    Range("A1010").Value = ""
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: `Range("A" & I + 3).Value = I`

Comment: Do you really want to run this for every change on the sheet?

Comment: @Kubie Because I need to have the ability to insert rows as needed and keep the lines numbers updated, without having to do as you suggested every time I Inserted.

Comment: @RussMcDaniel  fair point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim I As Integer
Set startRng = Cells(4, 1)

Application.EnableEvents = False
For I = 0 To 999
    startRng.Offset(I, 0) = I
Next
Range("A1010").Value = ""
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you.  Worked perfect.  Zero'd out on A4, but no biggie.  I worked around that.